# Combine 2 MongoDB collections into one api URL (not merging the collections, keeping them separate)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose

Im new to all this and need a little help please:

I have two Mongodb collections (Im using mongoose), **Clients** and **Options**.

They are not linked to each other.

I need to access both sets f data on one page in another app.

I can create an API Route pointing to each of these collections:

Clients: https://example.com/api/clients

Options: https://example.com/api/options

But what is the best way to merge these two into **one** API Route eg:

https://example.com/api/clients_options (URL is irrelevant I just need both sets of data Clients & Options to be accessible from both.)

Here is my Clients Model/Schema:

```
const ClientSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    client: String,
    brands: [
        {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: 'Brand'
        }
    ]

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Client', ClientSchema);
```

here is my Options Model/Schema:

```
const OptionsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    agencies: Array,
    asset_types: Array,
    format: Array,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Options', OptionsSchema);
```

I was thinking the best way to do this is to create a **master** Model/Schema that wraps both the **Clients** and **Options** schemas the way the **Client** Model/Schema wraps the *Brand* Schema.

eg:

```
const MasterSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    clients: {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: 'Clients'
       },
    options: {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: 'Options'
       }

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Master', MasterSchema);
```

But when I do this, my new Masters Model/Schema doesn't seem to populate with the existing Client and Option Model/Schemas, so my new **Master** Model/Schema stays blank and doesn't get created as a collection?

Is there a better way to do this?

**These are my Routes for each:**

```
//CLIENT API
    app.get('/api/clients',function(req, res){
        Client.find({})
            .populate({
                path: 'brands',
                populate: {
                    path: 'campaigns',
                    model: 'Campaign'
                } 
            }).exec(function(err, clients){
                if(err) {
                    console.log('ERROR!');
                } else {
                    let data = [];
                    clients.forEach(client => {

                        //console.log(client);
                        data.push(client);
                    });
                    res.send({clients: data});
                }
            });
    });
```

```
    //OPTIONS API
    app.get('/api/options',function(req, res){
        Options.find({})
            .exec(function(err, options){
                if(err) {
                    console.log('ERROR!');
                } else {
                    let data = [];
                    options.forEach(option => {

                        //console.log(client);
                        data.push(option);
                    });
                    res.send({options: data});
                }
            });
    });
```

I would like to merge the data of the two into a single api so that I can call only one API URL in another app to access all the data, but cant figure out how/the best way to do it?

Comment: What is in your controller?  The one that selects data and returns it to user? Show us ur routes.
Creating Collection will ref fields, will not automatically fill some data without actully having data in it that references those collections ...
What you will have to do is merge two collections response to one call

Comment: Added routes above for clarity, I need to make a single route that includes data from both collections.

Comment: Exactly, simply do Promise.all([Options.find().exec(), Client.find().exec()]) and add them to single object on results

Comment: thank you @noitse, Ive managed to figure it out, but, posted answer below, but I will try your method too, I need to get my head around promises properly, Im not too familiar with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive managed to figure it out, I did it in the following way:

```
//ALL DATA API
    app.get('/api/data',function(req, res){
        Client.find({})
            .populate({
                path: 'brands',
                populate: {
                    path: 'campaigns',
                    model: 'Campaign'
                } 
            }).exec(function(err, clients){
                if(err) {
                    console.log('ERROR!');
                } else {
                    let clientData = [];
                    clients.forEach(client => {

                        //console.log(client);
                        clientData.push(client);
                    });

                    Options.find({})
                        .exec(function(err, options){
                            if(err) {
                                console.log('ERROR!');
                            } else {
                                let optionsData = [];
                                options.forEach(option => {

                                    //console.log(client);
                                    optionsData.push(option);
                                });
                                res.send({clients: clientData, options: optionsData});
                            }
                        });
                }
            });
    });
```